# What's the best way to intersect more than two sets in immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

immutable.js has a `Set` object, and you can find the intersection of two sets via `set1.intersect(set2)`, but what if I have an arbitrarily long array of sets `[set1, set2, set3, set4,...]` and I want to find the intersection of them all? Is there an existing utility function in a common library that I should use? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set.prototype.intersect](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Set/intersect) is a varargs function (defined as `intersect(...collections: Array<Iterable<T>>): this`), so you can just do `set1.intersect(...sets)`.